# PHP Piping Data with f_open

Tags: php

I have a piece of code, the issue is the file "data" is over 8GB. This is very memory intensive. I want to reduce the usage of RAM and saw the `f_load` would be ideal, however, how could i explode this data?

This is my current code:

```
$data = file_get_contents("data");
$data = explode("|", $data);
foreach ($data as $d) { // rest of code
```

theoretically, i need to open a pipe, stream and close a pipe How would i go about this?

I've tried using `f_open` rather than `file_get_contents` but  errors started popping up so i'm doing something wrong and would really like to learn.

Comment: What errors `started popping up`?

Comment: You could use `readfile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `stream_get_line` to read your data block per block (with `|` as the delimiter character) : [PHP stream_get_line()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-line.php)

```
$fh = fopen('data', 'r'); // open the file in read-only mode

while( $d = stream_get_line($fh, 1000, '|') ) // read the file until the next |
{
    echo $d . PHP_EOL ; // display one block of data
}

fclose($fh); // close the file
```

Comment: would i fclose the file at the end of the script?

Comment: You close the file when you don't need to read anything from it anymore. The file handlers are closed automatically at the end of the script, but if you read several files, it can matter to close them asap.